# PySide2 Proxy model non-NOTIFYable properties warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

My QML application with PySide2 giving warnings at runtime

> QQmlExpression: Expression
>   file:///E:/kingpin/qml/main.qml:68:17
>   depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:
>       controller::project_proxy_list_model

Proxy model update with onTextChanged event, so how can i manage notify signal for proxy model ?

**app.py**

```
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml

class ElementListModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    TitleRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
    UrlRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setItemRoleNames(
            {ElementListModel.TitleRole: b"title", ElementListModel.UrlRole: b"url_image"}
        )

    @QtCore.Slot(str, QtCore.QUrl)
    def addItem(self, title, url):
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it.setData(title, ElementListModel.TitleRole)
        it.setData(url, ElementListModel.UrlRole)
        self.appendRow(it)


class controller(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    @QtCore.Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def project_proxy_list_model(self):
        return populate_project_list()


project_list_model = ElementListModel()
project_list_filter = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
project_list_filter.setSourceModel(project_list_model)
project_list_filter.setFilterRole(project_list_model.TitleRole)


def populate_project_list():
    entries = [
        ("one", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/one.png"),
        ("two", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/two.png"),
        ("three", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/three.png"),
        ("four", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/four.png"),
    ]
    for title, source in entries:
        project_list_model.addItem(title,source)
    return project_list_filter


controller = controller()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.addImportPath(current_dir)
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", controller)
filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "main.qml")
engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

if not engine.rootObjects():
    sys.exit(-1)
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 1380
    height: 776
    title: qsTr("test")

    Rectangle{
        id: bufferRectId
        width: 1380
        height: 738
        color: "#22252a"
        anchors.top: parent.top

        TextField{
            id: filterTextFieldId
            font {
                family: "Lato"
                pixelSize: 22
            }
            color: "dodgerblue"
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.topMargin: 38
            anchors.leftMargin: 850
            onTextChanged: controller.project_proxy_list_model.setFilterRegExp(text)
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 1280
            height: 590
            color: "transparent"
            anchors{
                top: parent.top
                left: parent.left
                topMargin: 110
                leftMargin: 65
        }
            GridView {
                id: thumbViewId
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 20
                cellWidth: 200
                cellHeight: 320
                model: controller.project_proxy_list_model
                delegate: ThumbDelegate {
                    source: model.url_image
                    title: model.title
                }
                focus: true
                clip: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ThumbDelegate.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.13


Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 180
    height: 270
    color: 'transparent'
    clip: true

    property alias source: thumbImageId.source
    property alias title: label.text

    Image {
        id: thumbImageId
        asynchronous: true
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: base
        width: parent.width
        height: 50
        color: '#484848'
        y: root.height
        Behavior on y { NumberAnimation {duration: 500} }
        Label {
            id: label
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            font.family: 'SF Pro Display'
            font.pointSize: 22
            color: 'white'
        }

        FastBlur {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: base
            radius: 64
            transparentBorder: false
    }
    }


    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: base.y = root.height - base.height
        onExited: base.y = root.height
        onClicked: {
            swipeViewAreaId.currentIndex = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not got that error but obviously I have had to modify your code since it is not a [MRE], an MRE would allow me to make a copy-paste and be able to get the error but your code cannot be executed, please provide an MRE .

Comment: I have made changes in code, And i found one more issue with Proxy model property (Proxy model are not updating properly onTextChanged event).  

link for images----
https://ibb.co/0QWx27k
https://ibb.co/dPP8WCz
https://ibb.co/g9X5FvH
https://ibb.co/VCgWgSD
https://ibb.co/X308L3C

Comment: I have tested with PySide2 5.13.2 and 5.14.1 and I don't see the warning message. Also I do not see any error in your code so it is probably a bug from an old version. What version of Python, PySide2 do you use and what is your OS?

Comment: Win 10 x64, Python 3.7.4, PySide2 5.13.1

Comment: Try updating pyside2

Comment: Ok, And Please try this...type "One" in Text field and thn  clear.May be you will see warning or random number of item in Gridview. no idea what's wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments I do not get the warning message, also that the code is valid so I can presume that it is an old bug.

But also as the OP points out there is another problem: every time a search is made, new elements are added to the model and that is caused because every time it is filtered, the "project_proxy_list_model" qproperty must be obtained, therefore this function is invoked , and in the logic of the OP is that 4 new items are loaded, which is wrong, the logic is to return the model and not use another method.

```py
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml

class ElementListModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    TitleRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
    UrlRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setItemRoleNames(
            {ElementListModel.TitleRole: b"title", ElementListModel.UrlRole: b"url_image"}
        )

    @QtCore.Slot(str, QtCore.QUrl)
    def addItem(self, title, url):
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it.setData(title, ElementListModel.TitleRole)
        it.setData(url, ElementListModel.UrlRole)
        self.appendRow(it)


class Controller(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.project_list_model = ElementListModel()
        self.project_list_filter = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.project_list_filter.setSourceModel(self.project_list_model)
        self.project_list_filter.setFilterRole(self.project_list_model.TitleRole)

        self.populate_project_list()

    @QtCore.Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def project_proxy_list_model(self):
        return self.project_list_filter

    def populate_project_list(self):
        entries = [
            ("one", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/one.png"),
            ("two", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/two.png"),
            ("three", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/three.png"),
            ("four", "file:///E:/qml_model/media/images/four.png"),
        ]
        for title, source in entries:
            self.project_list_model.addItem(title, source)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    controller = Controller()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.addImportPath(current_dir)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("controller", controller)
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```